# Showing the Matrix identity $A_{g\circ f,X,Z}=A_{g,Y,Z}\cdot A_{f,X,Y}$

Tags: linear-algebra

We want to show the indentity in a specific way that I did not understand, the definitions and theorems which are stated in the proof will be listed. The book is Bosch Linear Algebra page 95,

> Th4: $\psi:\operatorname{Hom}_K(V,W)\rightarrow K^{m\times n}$ with $f\mapsto
> > A_{f,X,Y}$ is an isomorphism.

This is the definition of $A_{f,X,Y}$:

Let $x_1,...,x_n=X$ be a basis of $V$ and $y_1,...,y_m=Y$ a basis of $W$. And $f:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear map then $A_{f,X,Y}=\big{(}(k_Y\circ f)(x_1),...,(k_Y\circ f)(x_n)\big{)}\in K^{m\times n}$ (The filevectornotation).

Where $k_Y$ was defined as an isomorphism $W\rightarrow K^m$, where each Vector of $W$ is described in its coordinates over the basis $Y$.

> We also know that matrixmultiplication is associative
>
> And also if $f:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear map and $X=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $Y=(y_1,...,y_m)$ are bases respective to the vectorspaces. Then
>   $$k_Y(f(a))=A_{f,X,Y}\cdot k_X(a)$$

Thus the diagram is commutative

[image: kk]

where $\bar{f}$ is defined as $x\mapsto A_{f,X,Y}\cdot x$

Now back to the proof, we want to show that $A_{g\circ f},X,Z=A_{g,Y,Z}\cdot A_{f,X,Y}$

The proof says:

Because of prior statements we have this diagram:

[image: gf]

where $\bar{f}$ is defined with $x\mapsto A_{f,X,Z}\cdot x$ and $\bar{g}$ with $y\mapsto A_{g,Y,Z}\cdot y$. Due to associativity one sees that $A_{g\circ f,X,Z}$ and $A_{g,Y,Z}\cdot A_{f,X,Y}$ are matrices that describe the linear map $g\circ f$ according to the basis $X$ and $Z$. And with Th4 one then derives $A_{g\circ f,X,Z}=A_{g,Y,Z}\cdot A_{f,X,Y}$

I don't understand what it means when ***a matrice describes a linear map according to bases $X$ and $Z$***. And I also dont understand how you can derive from Th4 if two matrices fullfil this condition then the matrices are the same.

My thoughts so far:

I haven't included it but we know there exists a map $\bar{z}$ such that $\bar{z}:K^{p}\rightarrow K^{m}$ and $\bar{z}(u)= A_{g\circ f,X,Z}\cdot u$ such that $g\circ f= k_Z^{-1}\circ \bar{z} \circ k_X$. And because of second commutative diagram I drew we know that $g\circ f = (k_Z^{-1}\circ \bar{g} \circ k_Y)\circ(k_Y^{-1}\circ\bar{f}\circ k_X)=k_Z^{-1}\circ \bar{z'} \circ k_X$,

where $\bar{z'}:K^{p}\rightarrow K^{m}$ is given by $\bar{z'}(x)=A_{g,Y,Z}\cdot A_{f,X,Y}(x)$. This identity of the function can be proved by choosing an arbitrary $x\in K^{p}$ and using the associativy of matrixmultiplication.

Now how does the author continue the proof, how does he argue to show the identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This theorem is just about the following statement:

> When bases $X$ of $V$ and $Y$ of $W$ are fixed, then $m\times n$ matrices *correspond to* linear maps $V\to W$.

Your second commutative diagram shows that
$$k_Z(g\circ f\, (u)) =\bar g(\bar f(k_X(u)))$$
Where right hand side 
$$=A_{g,Y,Z}\cdot (A_{f,X,Y}\cdot k_X(u)) =(A_{g,Y,Z}\cdot A_{f,X,Y}) \cdot k_X(u)$$
While, the first commutative diagram applied to $g\circ f$ yields to
$$k_Z(g\circ f\, (u)) = \overline{g\circ f}(k_X(u)) =A_{g\circ f, X, Z}\cdot k_X(u)$$
Since $k_X$ is an isomorphism, these two together imply $A_{g,Y,Z}\cdot A_{f,X,Y}=A_{g\circ f, X, Z}$. 
(Alternatively, plug in $u=x_i$ to obtain the statement for the $i$th columns.)